# Order by mod with float attribute

Tags: mysql

I have a query with that's results (it is ordered by second attribute):

```
Driver1   4,12    1
Driver2   3,11    2
Driver3   1,34    3
Driver4   0,45    4
Driver5   0,22    5
Driver6   0,10    6
```

And I want to order it by the last attribute mod 3. In this example, it was:

```
Driver1   4,12    1
Driver3   1,34    3
Driver5   0,22    5
Driver2   3,11    2
Driver4   0,45    4
Driver6   0,10    6
```

What can I add into my query to obtain that?

I made `SELECT * FROM (myquery) ORDER BY third_atrribute%2,second_attribute DESC`
but appears:

```
Driver2   3,11    2
Driver4   0,45    4
Driver6   0,10    6
Driver1   4,12    1
Driver3   1,34    3
Driver5   0,22    5
```

Comment: I can't recognize any order in expected result set

Comment: Its order by third (last) attribute with %2

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: show your table definition

Comment: table you query data from. and I still can't get how 3rd column (1,3,5,2,4,6) ir ordered